# Wordpress Block (checkout and billing) are not being translater properly

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i have been creating an eCommerce with wordpress and woocommerce

Upon installing wordpress i did downloaded the Portuguese version and afterwards installed the plugin mentioned previously. My issue at the moment is that the checkout and billing page are being displayed in english, even though when i enter the edit mode it displays all in the intended language (portuguese)

Things i tried to do:
1)to make sure there was no interference with other plugins or themes, i did a clean install of wordpress and only woocommerce as plugin and the issue still occurs

2)tried using loco translator plugin although the mentioned strings from those blocks are still not being translated

3)used the string locator plugin and tried to replace the intended string for the portuguese version although with no change

So far the only thing that worked was using “say what” plugin replacing the string for the one i wanted, but this does seem more like a short term solution

Other thing that worked was also reverting to the legacy mode instead of blocks, and it displayed properly, but once i go back to the blocks it goes to english again

Is the issue known? Is there anything i can do?

Comment: This seems to be a bug that you need you report in WooCommerce plugin support pages. As cart and checkout blocks are recent and still in current development, you should use legacy Classic cart and checkout (shortcode), for the moment.